# Set text of following input field. .value does not work

Tags: javascript, html

I want to set text of input field using .value. After setting the value of input field, when I click on that field the text disappears. I don't want text to disappear.

The input html is as follow:

```
<input aria-invalid="true" aria-required="true" data-automation-id="address-form-firstName" 
tealeafid="COAC2ShpAddrFirstName" name="firstName" initialvalue="" class="field-input field-input-- 
error field-input--primary" id="firstName" value="">
```

Setting the value of this input:

```
let name= document.querySelector("#firstName");
name.value = "First Name of user";
```

This html tag is present on Walmart website. Is there any solution?

Comment: So, you're saying that code, setting `name.value = "FirstName"`, does in fact work, but that clicking in the field later on clears it out?

Comment: I thought the same @HereticMonkey but seems that he wants it the other way.

Comment: Yes when i click the text disappears.

Comment: @MyThemesCafe, Here is your same code https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/BayyyxQ but it doesn't disappear.. Whether you need this text should disappear?

Comment: It appears as though you are using more than just JavaScript and HTML. Do you have some kind of other framework running?

Comment: It dissapears because of whatever code that you don't shared. Like you have it in your example it will not dissapear. Please add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) where we can test your code.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the text to be disappeared try *placeholder* property:

```js
let name= document.querySelector("#firstName");
name.placeholder = "FirstName";
```

```html
<input aria-invalid="true" aria-required="true" data-automation-id="address-form-firstName" 
tealeafid="COAC2ShpAddrFirstName" name="firstName" initialvalue="" class="field-input field-input-- 
error field-input--primary" id="firstName" value="">
```

Comment: Actually this is the way to go. Placeholders exists there for a reason. Better if you add it directly as an HTML attribute but I guess the requirement was to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You should add an EventListener to your input

```
let name= document.querySelector("#firstName");
name.value = "FirstName";
name.addEventListener("click", function(){
  name.value = "";
});
```

CodePen : https://codepen.io/abdelhedi/pen/qBEEEYw